# Control on booktabs elements

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl, rowcolor

I need to make a similar table:
[image]

I get something like that

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{cyan!30}{white}
        \begin{table}[htbp!]    
            \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
                \toprule
                \rowcolor{cyan!60}
                $l$ &  0  &  1  &  2  &  3  &  4  \\ \midrule
                letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\ 
                letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
                letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
                letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
                letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is any simple way to control (color, thicknes, distances, ...) on booktabs elements?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sorry, I added MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, colortbl, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}% select color according to your wish/taste
\rowcolors{2}{cyan!20}{white}    
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
        \toprule[4pt]% <-- option for rule thicknes
        \rowcolor{cyan!40}
        $l$ &  0  &  1  &  2  &  3  &  4  \\ \midrule
        letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
        letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
        letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
        letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
        letter   & $s$ & $p$ & $d$ & $f$ & $g$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about  rule colors and thickness?

Comment: @sergiokapone, momentary I'm faced with uploading problems, consequently my answer is not complete. I will complete asap.

Comment: @sergiokapone, now I finally siucceed to upload recent version of code, and add image of table.

Comment: @Zarko: Needless to load `colortbl` if you load `xcolor` with option `[table]` (I love minimalistic codes ;o))

Comment: @Bernard, I overlooked, that OP have loaded it. Of course, it is surplus to load it again (it is loaded by `xcolor` already). I delete it. Thank you.